# Clojure - How i can count vector of entry maps

Tags: clojure

How i can count mobile and web access discarding a nil values from a list of maps? the output should be anything like this " Statistic mobile = 1 web = 2", but all is imutable on other languagens a simple i++ resolve but how is in clojure. thanks.

```
        def data [{:name "app1" :type "mobile" }
        {:name "site1" :type "web" }
        {:name "site1" :type "web" }
        {:name "boot" :type nil }]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
(frequencies (map :type data))
```

gives

```
{"mobile" 1, "web" 2, nil 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user=> (for [[k v] (group-by :type data) :when k] [k (count v)])
(["mobile" 1] ["web" 2])
```